# Bash, replace group match with other variable

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have file with names similar to the following, where `v` is a variable part every time:

`_vvvv_id_vvvv.txt`

I want to replace `id` every time with another variable `$myvar`. I'm using this regex to isolate the id part: `'^_(.+)_.*\.txt$'`. Now I want to replace the id captured in group match 1 with `$myvar`.

There will always be only one and one only matched group.

I cannot use replace since this is a plausible case:

`_vvvid_id_vvvvid.txt`

This is different than [Replacing regex groups with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580759/replacing-regex-groups-with-sed) since the part before and after the group match are variable, and I need to use a regex that will ALSO match the whole file name, not just the id part.

Example:

```
$regex='^_(.+)_.*\.txt$'
$myvar='bar'
$f='_12345_23_678.txt'
$result=*sed or awk magic*

echo $result # echo _12345_bar_678.txt
```

Thank you

Comment: Your post uses a mix of Perl and Bourne Shell syntax ...

Comment: @Grobu oh yes, my bad, old habits die hard! I hope the point passed accross nevertheless!

Answer (score 3):

No sed or awk required:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

regex='(_[^_]+_)[^_]+(.*)'
myvar='bar'
f='_12345_23_678.txt'
[[ $f =~ $regex ]] && result="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${myvar}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
echo "$result"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
_12345_bar_678.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Another suggestion:

```
#! /bin/bash

replace()
  {
  local IFS='_'
  local Parts

  read -a Parts <<<"$1"
  Parts[2]="$2"
  echo "${Parts[*]}"
  }

myvar='bar'
f='_12345_23_678.txt'

result="$(replace "$f" "$myvar")"

echo "result is \"$result\""
```

No SED or AWK required either.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

An `awk` based solution:

```bash
f='_12345_23_678.txt'
myvar='bar'

awk -v var="$myvar" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} {$3 = var} 1' <<< "$f"

_12345_bar_678.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't care about capturing the id since you're going to discard it, it's the rest that you should capture in groups in order to produce them in your output :

```
regex='^(_[^_]*_)[^_]*(_.*\.txt)$'
myvar='bar'
f='_12345_23_678.txt'
result=$(echo "$f" | sed -E "s/$regex/\1$myvar\2/")

echo $result # echo _12345_bar_678.txt
```

In this regex, the first group captures up to the id, the second captures what comes afterward. The `sed` command matches the whole filename then replaces it by what comes before the id + your var + what comes after the id.

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/s5T5Kl).

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using `zsh`:

```
myvar='bar'
f='_12345_23_678.txt'
print _${${(s:_:)f}[1]}_${myvar}_${${(s:_:)f}[3]}
```

Output:

```
_12345_bar_678.txt
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/t7IsschWPSmxSJ0rzVY93tDI2MQ03sg43szcQq@kokSdq6AoM69EIV6lWqVao9gq3kozrTbaMLYWKADWW4sqYxxb@/8/AA)